# How to make a custom date display text in the input on a jQuery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

im having trouble with the following: I have a jQuery datepicker which is bound to a `<input>` field. What i want is, instead of the standard date display in the input field "MM/dd/yyyy" to be able to display the start and end of the week of the currently selected day, for example

if 25th of Decemeber 2012 is selected, 
then in the input field i would like to show "Dec.24 - Dec.30"

Calculating the start/end week days and the text formating is not a problem and i already have it.
The problem i'm having is when trying to set the input field's value to the custom text representation using

```
$("#datepickerInput").val('custom text')
```

then the datepicker date is set to todays date, instead of preserving its previously set value.

is there a way to achieve this somehow?

thanks

Comment: Is there any stuff you have worked on? or your tries? or where you find yourself stuck? all we need is code. Plz paste it or better to make a fiddle for it.

Comment: The problem with what you want to do is that the DatePicker won't know what date you actually picked if there's a custom text. It's possible to do what you want... but you'll have to be clever. It's not straight forward.

Comment: @Jai, there are some fiddles bellow in the answers that illustrate this problem exactly as i described it. any ideas are welcome :)

Comment: @AymanSafadi, i guess im not that clever after all, so im looking for help :) There is a property in the jQuery datepicker called "format" but its too bad it is only a string. If it would be a function that allows you to return custom text representation, that would be great, but its just a string. Feel free to advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using moment.js date library to adjust dates and output formats. Parsing dates is simply a lot easier when using a library that has many methods to compare, subtract , add  and manipulate formats.

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker().change(function() {
    var d = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    $(this).val(formatDatePickerDisplay(d))
})
/* trigger change to update display on page load*/
.change();


function formatDatePickerDisplay(d) {   
    if (!d) {
        return '';
    }
    var currDate = moment(d),
        monday = moment(currDate).day(1).format('MMM D'),
        friday = moment(currDate).day(5).format('MMM D');

    return monday + ' - ' + friday;

}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7tTnV/3/

Moment.js docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/

**EDIT**: the only issue with both solutions provided so far is that `datepicker` can't parse the displayed value to a current date to highlight when you open it. There are alternate methods to displaying datepiacker that would allow you to update an alternate field that would be displayed to user and actual date picker input would not be displayed. This would allow for proper current date highlighting

Comment: thank you for the asnwer, but that is exactly my problem, datepicker not being able to preserve the selected date and always reseting it to Today. I thought maybe datepicker keeps its internal value for the date and that the text representation can be modified as desired, but i guess that is not the case. As far as the altField, that is not what im looking for, because the designs i have to implement this include just this one datepicker. thanx anyway

Comment: only need one datepicker but update another field. SImple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/charlietfl/7tTnV/6/   You could assign datePicker to a button instead.  see demos

Comment: here's an alternate layout, uses datepicker button option, only see button for datepicker and populate other field http://jsfiddle.net/charlietfl/7tTnV/7/

Comment: thank you. your last fiddle is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var d = $('#datepickerInput').datepicker('getDate');
$('#datepickerInput').val(getMonday(d) + ' - ' + getSunday(d));
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YB5HY/)

Comment: thanks for the fiddle. As i mentioned in my very first post, the formating of the text representation is not a problem. What bothers me is what happens when you select some date. The text representation is ok, but click to open the datepicker and you will notice that it is always selecting Today.

Answer (score 1):

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/2h7Sj/

I borrowed some of the `getMonday` and `getSunday` logic from @Palash (but fixed a bug).

This solution allows you to pick a specific date *and* select a date range.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="dateRange" />
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenDate" />​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#dateRange').datepicker({
    altField: '#hiddenDate',
    firstDay: 1,
    onSelect: function(dateText, dateRange) {
        var dateRange = $(dateRange);

        var months       = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            hiddenDate = $('#hiddenDate'),
            theDate = new Date(dateText),
            dayOfTheWeek = theDate.getDay(),
            mondayOffset = theDate.getDate() - dayOfTheWeek + (dayOfTheWeek == 0 ? -6 : 1),
            sundayOffset = theDate.getDate() - dayOfTheWeek + (dayOfTheWeek == 0 ? 0 : 7),
            monday       = new Date(theDate.setDate(mondayOffset)),
            sunday       = new Date(theDate.setDate(sundayOffset)),
            mondayText   = months[monday.getMonth()] + '. ' + monday.getDate(),
            sundayText   = months[sunday.getMonth()] + '. ' + sunday.getDate(),
            rangeText    = mondayText + ' - ' + sundayText;

        $(this).val(rangeText);
        $(dateRange).data('rangetext', rangeText);
    },
    beforeShow: function(dateRange) {
        var hiddenDate = $('#hiddenDate');
        $(dateRange).val(hiddenDate.val());
    },
    onClose: function(selectedDateText, dateRange) {
        dateRange = $(dateRange);

        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $('#hiddenDate').val('');
        } else {
            if(selectedDateText.indexOf('-') < 0 && dateRange.data('rangetext')) {
                console.log('data-rangetext', dateRange.data('rangetext'));
                $(this).val(dateRange.data('rangetext'));
            }
        }
    }
});​
```